# Modify WooCommerce Breadcrumbs for Custom Category Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I want to create a WordPress Page that displays a list of WooCommerce (WC) products from a specific product category. This page will act as a custom Product Category Archive.

The problem I have is using the default WC breadcrumbs. When the viewer is on the Single Product page and they click on the Category name in the WC breadcrumbs, they are brought back to the default WC category archive template and NOT my custom page.

Is it possible to modify the WC breadcrumbs to link back to a custom WordPress page?

Answer (score 0):

you can override woocommerce in your theme and going to theme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php and then modify your code.